# How to get Masonry to work with Bootstrap 5 Cards inside of Tabs? (Without jQuery)

Tags: bootstrap-5, masonry

Has anyone figured out how to get [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) to work with Bootstrap 5 Cards inside the Tabs component and without jQuery?

Currently, when you navigate each tab except the first tab, all content becomes stack instead of showing the Masonry layout like the first tab

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
      
      Home tab
      
      <div class="row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3">
          <figure class="p-3 mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-white">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has a regular title and short paragraph of text below it.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img" width="100%" height="260" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Card image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Card image</text></svg>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3 text-end">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is another card with title and supporting text below. This card has some additional content to make it slightly taller overall.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    </div>
   
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
    
    Contact tab
      
      <div class="row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3">
          <figure class="p-3 mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-white">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has a regular title and short paragraph of text below it.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img" width="100%" height="260" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Card image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Card image</text></svg>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3 text-end">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is another card with title and supporting text below. This card has some additional content to make it slightly taller overall.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/imzenko/pen/GRMvZKw

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just add ".active" class on all div where ".tab-pane" is:

Home tab

    
    Contact tab

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.2.2/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <button class="nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      <button class="nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#nav-contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
      
      Home tab
      
      <div class="row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3">
          <figure class="p-3 mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-white">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has a regular title and short paragraph of text below it.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img" width="100%" height="260" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Card image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Card image</text></svg>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3 text-end">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is another card with title and supporting text below. This card has some additional content to make it slightly taller overall.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    </div>
   
    <div class="tab-pane active fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">
    
    Contact tab
      
      <div class="row" data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3">
          <figure class="p-3 mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top" width="100%" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Image cap" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Image cap</text></svg>
  
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card bg-primary text-white text-center p-3">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-white">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card text-center">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This card has a regular title and short paragraph of text below it.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img card-img" width="100%" height="260" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Card image" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">Card image</text></svg>
  
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card p-3 text-end">
          <figure class="mb-0">
            <blockquote class="blockquote">
              <p>A well-known quote, contained in a blockquote element.</p>
            </blockquote>
            <figcaption class="blockquote-footer mb-0 text-muted">
              Someone famous in <cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">This is another card with title and supporting text below. This card has some additional content to make it slightly taller overall.</p>
            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

If preview method don't give you the result you're looking for try this:

https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/GQoVey

with "imagesLoaded" here:

https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4.1.4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js